# Broken apt system prevents running wireshark

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireshark, apt

I have trouble running `wireshark`:

$ wireshark 
wireshark: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

According to [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libQt5Widgets.so.5&searchon=contents), that library is in [libqt5widgets5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libqt5widgets5)

That package is installed in my system:

```
$ dpkg-query -L libqt5widgets5
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9.5
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libqt5widgets5
/usr/share/doc/libqt5widgets5/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libqt5widgets5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9
/usr/share/doc/libqt5widgets5/changelog.Debian.gz
```

But it seems broken?

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9.5
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9.5': No such file or directory
```

Why could this be? What are my options?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the package?

Comment: have you tried `apt install --reinstall libqt5widgets5`?